# Bounding a sum of numbers from the multiset $\{1,2,\ldots,n,n-1,n-2,\ldots, 1 \}$?

Tags: combinatorics

> ***Question:*** If $n$ is a nonzero positive number I write $A:=\{1,2,\ldots,n,n-1,n-2,\ldots,1 \}$. How many different sums are possible such that $${\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\ldots +\alpha_i\above 1.5pt n^2}  \leq {1\above 1.5pt 3}$$ and $\alpha_i \in A$.

For example consider the set $A:=\{1,2,3,2,1\}$. Then $n=3$ and so $n^2=9$. Inspection shows the sums: $1+3=2+2$ and $1+1+3=1+2+2=2+3$ yield ratios greater than ${1\above 1.5pt 3}$ when divided by $9$. Then we have $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$ $\{3\}$, $\{1,1\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ as admissible sums.

Note 1: I struggled coming up with a good title.

Comment: $A$ should be a multiset, since a set does not have repetitions.

Comment: Noted. So the title should read "Bounding a sum of numbers from a finite multiset" ?

Comment: Or just from $\{1,2,\ldots,n,n-1,n-2,\ldots, 1\}$.

Comment: Wait, is it $\{1,2,\ldots,n,n-1,n-2,\ldots, 1\}$ or just $\{1,2,\ldots,n,n-1,n-2, 1\}$?

Comment: So the answer for $n=3$ is $8$ (counting the two occurances of $\{1\}$ etc.)? And $\emptyset$ is not counted?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes !

Comment: Isn't that the answer for $n = 3$ is $10$? $$\{1\}, \{1'\}, \{1,1'\}, \{2\}, \{2'\}, \{1,2\}, \{1',2\}, \{1,2'\}, \{1',2'\}, \{3\} $$ Anyway, if this is the way you would like to count, then a crude asymptotics tells that the fraction of all multi-subsets satisfying the given condition is at most $\mathcal{O}(1/n)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @SangchulLee you are correct. I forgot to notice there are 2 ways to pick $\{1,1\}$ and $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee could you clarify "is at most $\mathcal{O}(1/n)$ "

Comment: To be precise, we have $$ [\text{number of multi-subsets $\{\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_i\}$ satisfying the condition}] \leq \frac{C}{n} \times 2^{2n+1}$$ for some constant $C>0$.